# Checkout Only One Product Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm a buy Now Button On Shop Page That Redirect to:

```
checkout/?add-to-cart={product_id}
```

It Working Well But The Problem that the user get to checkout all the product on his cart and not the one that he only selected, so how can I add the product to the cart, and Redirect the user To Pay/Checkout One
The Product That He Clicked 'Buy Now' For.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to first clear the cart and then add to cart and checkout the product.

Using a clear [cart code](https://gist.github.com/kloon/4541017) and slightly modifying it will help you:

Add to your function.php file function to enable a param `?clear-cart` on any url to clear the cart, now we can slightly modify the code to read the next custom param `?my-add-to-cart` with the `product-id` and add that to the cart.

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['clear-cart'] ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
   if ( isset( $_GET['my-add-to-cart'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/checkout?add-to-cart='.$_GET['my-add-to-cart']));
    }
}
```

You can now set links on buy now button as `checkout/?clear-cart&add-to-cart={product_id}`

The reason I am using a custom `my-add-to-cart` param instead of the default is to let our code first clear the cart and then go to checkout instead of running into possible issues of simultaneous action triggers of empty cart and add to cart together.

Comment: Thank you For Your Answer, But this Way the customer will lose all the product he had previously in his cart, Am I right ?

Comment: yes, definitely....

Comment: You could do something like save the cart contents in db temporarily and clear the cart and checkout... and then after order completion add the items back to the cart....but that would be slightly complex...or you can move the items from cart to wishlist if the cart has items before emptying it (use YITH wishlist plugin).